# Parallel query execution in Mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql

I'm working with MySQL version 5.7 and I have a query that uses UNION ALL with two subqueries. The problem is that these subqueries are executed sequentially, which leads to slow query performance. Is there a way to execute these subqueries in parallel within the context of a UNION ALL operation in MySQL 5.7? Also, I'm wondering how MariaDB handles this issue.

I tried to avoid using UNION ALL by using LEFT JOIN, but it resulted in an even slower performance.

Comment: Your options to speed up queries include improving index usage or rewriting logic to use joins. You cannot have async/await in SQL, which is not necessarily a bad thing.

Comment: I tried various optimizations, such as creating indexes and improving SQL code, but they only resulted in small improvements.

Comment: Subquery performance is a know limitation, they even wrote [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimizing-subqueries.html).

Comment: I agree, but I'm searching for a possible solution for executing queries in parallel within a union all, if it's possible at all.

Comment: I'm positively sure it isn't. I've never head of an async SQL implementation, let alone in MySQL/5.

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions that will reduce time required to complete.

Comment: MySQL 8.0 has a few simple cases where it uses multiple threads.  But I don't think they handle your use case.